# Catkin_make error: virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory

Tags: ros, catkin-make, beaglebone, armhf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Relative noob having enough knowledge to get into trouble....
Attempting to compile robot_localization package (along with a couple of drivers- ublox gps and christa imu).  Goes along fine at first:

```
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/media/sdcard/catkin_ws/build"
####
####
#### Running command: "make -j1 -l1" in "/media/sdcard/catkin_ws/build"
####
[  1%] Built target filter_utilities
[  1%] Built target _robot_localization_generate_messages_check_deps_SetDatum
[  1%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  1%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  1%] Built target _robot_localization_generate_messages_check_deps_SetPose
[  1%] Built target geographic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target robot_localization_generate_messages_cpp
[  2%] Built target robot_localization_gencpp
[  3%] Built target filter_base
[  3%] Built target ekf
[  4%] Built target ros_filter_utilities
[  5%] Built target ukf
[  5%] Building CXX object robot_localization/CMakeFiles/ros_filter.dir/src/ros_filter.cpp.o
In file included from /opt/ros/indigo/include/ros/ros.h:40:0,
                 from /opt/ros/indigo/include/tf2_ros/buffer.h:38,
#################################################################
Then fails at the very end of the compilation:
                                  ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/rosconsole/macros_generated.h:60:36: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_LOG’
 #define ROS_DEBUG_NAMED(name, ...) ROS_LOG(::ros::console::levels::Debug, std::string(ROSCONSOLE_NAME_PREFIX) + "." + name, __VA_ARGS__)
                                    ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/tf2_ros/message_filter.h:53:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘ROS_DEBUG_NAMED’
   ROS_DEBUG_NAMED("message_filter", "MessageFilter [target=%s]: ", fmt, getTargetFramesString().c_str(), __VA_ARGS__)
   ^
/opt/ros/indigo/include/tf2_ros/message_filter.h:282:5: note: in expansion of macro ‘TF2_ROS_MESSAGEFILTER_DEBUG’
     TF2_ROS_MESSAGEFILTER_DEBUG("%s", "Cleared");
     ^
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make[2]: *** [robot_localization/CMakeFiles/ros_filter.dir/src/ros_filter.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [robot_localization/CMakeFiles/ros_filter.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j1 -l1" failed
ubuntu@arm:/media/sdcard/catkin_ws$
#############################
```

This is being performed on a Beaglebone Black with:  Linux arm 4.1.1-ti-r2 #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Jul 8 18:40:57 UTC 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux

I am out of ideas now.  There should be plenty of memory:

```
ubuntu@arm:/media/sdcard/catkin_ws$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:        502088      43824     458264        380       3104       9768
-/+ buffers/cache:      30952     471136
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Any ideas are gratefully accepted! Perhaps this is too much for this board/sd card mix?  (sd card is vfat FAT32)
Thanks in advance,
B2256

---

Thank you allenh1.

It seems that I was also able to find an answer based upon the swap file solution while waiting for answers. Other BBB users may also try [this](http://charette.no-ip.com:81/programming/2015-06-07_BeagleBoneBlack/) for a similar solution. It turns out that allenh1's point of the BBB only having 512MB is well founded and that "anything non-trivial will fail to compile with an out-of-memory error" according to the second source. Compiling was slow as noted, but appears to work aside from a clock skew warning. Thank you all again.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214767/catkin_make-error:--virtual-memory-exhausted:-cannot-allocate-memory/) by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on ROS Answers with karma: 162 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [b2256](https://answers.ros.org/users/21768/b2256/) on 2015-07-28**:
sorry- hard to read formatting.  Previewed fine though.

media output:
ubuntu@arm:/media/sdcard/catkin_ws$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mmcblk1p1  3.6G  1.2G  2.2G  36% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            231M  4.0K  231M   1% /dev
tmpfs            50M  136K   49M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            246M     0  246M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/mmcblk0p1  7.4G   52M  7.4G   1% /media/sdcard
ubuntu@arm:/media/sdcard/catkin_ws$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That error  is saying you ran out of RAM to compile... Which is reasonable, as you only have 512MB. Consider increasing the size of your swap partition. You could plug a usb stick in and format it as swap. Suppose it's `/dev/sdb1` and formatted.

```
$ sudo mkswap /dev/sdb1
$ sudo swapon /dev/sdb1
```

Compiling will be quite slow, but you should be able to do it now.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AniketDatar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26779/aniketdatar/) on 2016-05-06**:
Hello i have swap memory of 2GB on my raspberry pi 2 B still i get error of virtual memory exhausted and half of swap always stay free i am running catkin_make with -j1 argument

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2016-05-16**:
Have you considered cross-compiling? Where exactly does it fail?

**Comment by [AniketDatar](https://answers.ros.org/users/26779/aniketdatar/) on 2016-05-23**:
thanks for suggestion i found out that the issue was with the version of compiler. now its working fine on PI.
but i have another problem of same program which builds successfully but while execution i get root process killed ros error -11 (i think segmentation fault) on intel pc with core i5 laptop

**Comment by [bfdmetu](https://answers.ros.org/users/45011/bfdmetu/) on 2020-05-24**:
Can you explain how solve the problem_ Upgrade C++ compiler or something